# Using PHP to return table names

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use PHP to return a list of my tables containing a specific word.

I found mysql_tablename but apparently this function has been deprecated. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I remember it's doable from a query to the MySQL server, something with `schema` in it, can't remember exactly...

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer, the word I'm looking for (a username) is in one of the fields within one of the tables, not within one of the table names. But I think I'll be able to work it out, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
$q = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'pattern'");

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_row($q))
{
    echo $row[0]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: I think your answer it's not ok because a database needs to be selected in order to work.

Comment: so you can use `SHOW TABLES IN database LIKE 'pattern'`

Comment: The docs here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-tablename.php state its optional (in [])

Answer (score 1):

You can Issue a query against information_schema.tables, should be something like

```
select * from information_schema.tables where table_name like '%keyword%';
```

Comment: 'information_schema.tables' seems to always return the same result? 'Resource id #6'

Answer (score 1):

Query the MySQL server for it:

```
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE table_schema = 'db_name'
  [AND table_name LIKE 'wild']
```

**[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html)**

---

For tables containing a specific word, use the `LIKE` keyword to match it in the `WHERE` clause.